Enhancing mathematical proof skills using AI (in university teaching)
I would appreciate ideas on good practice in the use of AI among mathematics and statistics students to improve their critical thinking in the development of mathematical proofs.
I am wondering about students:

sourcing a proof of a particular theorem, or a property of a parameter, and then being asked to critique the proof;

developing a different proof to that already provided using generative AI prompts;


or

a combination of 1) and 2), above.

Are any AI tools particularly helpful for this sort of thing? Would using them require payment of a fee by the institution or students?

Best chatgpt-like models are still dumber than most university students when it comes to STEM tasks. I'd recommend checking out https://www.wolframalpha.com/ instead. It solves math and physics problems and Pro subscription allows you to see step-by-step solution. It's a solid tool that has been around for decade.
